# Using static in page object (Cypress)

Tags: javascript, typescript, static, cypress, pageobjects

Looking through various examples of implementing e2e tests on Cypress, I came across the fact that many people use the method of creating a new object, instead of using `static`. Why do they do this? Why not use `static` for page-object methods, because we don't change any data in the class itself and, accordingly, don't communicate to `this`, and we don't need to have multiple instances of the same page (or I don't see a scenario for using this). I understand that Selenium uses page factory and because of this it is necessary to create a new object, but I did not find an analogy in Cypress.

**Example of creating a new object:**

```
import { BasePage } from './BasePageClass'
import { navMenu } from './NavigationMenuClass';
import { queryPage } from './QueryPageClass';

export class MainPage extends BasePage  {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.mainElement = 'body > .banner';
  }

  verifyElements() {
    super.verifyElements();
    cy.get(this.mainElement).find('.container h1').should('be.visible');
  }

  switchToQueryingPage() {
    navMenu.switchToQueryingPage();
    queryPage.verifyElements();
  }
};

export const mainPage = new MainPage();
```

**Example using static:**

```
import { BasePage } from './BasePageClass'
import { navMenu } from './NavigationMenuClass';
import { queryPage } from './QueryPageClass';

export default class MainPage extends BasePage  {
  static mainElement = 'body > .banner';

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  static verifyElements() {
    super.verifyElements();
    cy.get(MainPage.mainElement).find('.container h1').should('be.visible');
  }

  static switchToQueryingPage() {
    navMenu.switchToQueryingPage();
    queryPage.verifyElements();
  }
};
```

Comment: I haven`t seen such examples, but examples to use custom commands instead. Can you share the links to such examples and why they are considered better?

Comment: @RosenMihaylov
https://github.com/Hypercubed/cypress-page-object-pattern
https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/01/03/stop-using-page-objects-and-start-using-app-actions/
https://medium.com/reactbrasil/deep-diving-pageobject-pattern-and-using-it-with-cypress-e60b9d7d0d91
...and many other examples on github. I have also seen custom commands, but in my case I need to have a large number of methods with the possibility of inheritance (for example, for modal windows, there is a lot of the same logic).

Comment: I'm not saying that they are definitely better (that's the point of this question), but I haven't seen any examples with static, and one of the examples is described in the official Cypress blog.
P.S. I also use the state storage method (for example, via request), but I need to perform a specific action at least once through the UI, and the application is quite large.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have been told that composition is better practice than inheritance, and had only used that, but it is nice to read some other good practice, since I do not believe my way is the only way. I think that you can use custom commands in the place of those static ones and still make the same result. Also a custom command can be used in every file - an inheritance like that seems to be usefull only on a single file.

Comment: @RosenMihaylov The official documentation says that you should not enter everything in the custom command. If this can exist as a separate function, then don't put it in command. Source: https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html#1-Don%E2%80%99t-make-everything-a-custom-command. And why can't I use classes in different files? You can plug them in using modules.

Comment: thanks thats valuable info

Comment: @RosenMihaylov  True: composition is better practice than inheritance. Can you share some code samples around that, specifically around Cypress.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a composition of commands my seniors have taught me to use. I have a function `buyProduct`, but it requires several steps and I have made them in different commands that can be used in different cases:

```
it('buyProductAsCustomer', ()=>{
    cy.login(customer)
    cy.shopFe_openProductByName(product.name)
    cy.shopFe_addProductToCart()
    cy.shopFe_openCheckoutFromCart()
    cy.shopFe_selectPaymentMethod("payWithCreditCardMethod")
    cy.shopFe_fillCheckoutFormAsCustomer(customer)
    cy.shopFe_checkoutPageGetOrderData()
    cy.shopFe_submitCheckoutForm()
    cy.shopFe_completePaymentWithCreditCard()
});
it('buyProductAsGuest', ()=>{
    cy.shopFe_openProductByName(product.name)
    cy.shopFe_addProductToCart()
    cy.shopFe_openCheckoutFromCart()
    cy.shopFe_selectPaymentMethod("payWithCashMethod")
    cy.shopFe_fillCheckoutFormAsGuest(guest)
    cy.shopFe_checkoutPageGetOrderData()
    cy.shopFe_submitCheckoutForm()
    cy.shopFe_completePaymentWithCreditCard()
});
```

These 2 cases can be done in command with several variables, but in time those variables tend to increase tenfold. Thus we separate them into smaller repeatable parts that can be combined in different ways.